# Select em jsonb aninhado - postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

Eu tive dificuldade em encontrar os valores em uma base, pois todos os exemplos citam a mesma forma de encontrar informações em jsons simples.

Mas um amigo do trabalho me passou e solução e vim compartilhar.

a pergunta inicial era: Como fazer um select em um json aninhado???

Como este:

```
{"vehicle":[{"vehicle_type":"Truck","car_make":"Lotus","car_model":"Esprit","quantity":7,"seats":7,"price_hour":16,"price_day":147,"color":["Purple","Pink","Blue","White"]}]}
```

Para visualizar a estrutura é possível utilizar o https://jsoneditoronline.org

Answer (score 0):

A resposta que trago utiliza select com regex:

```
select * from example
where example.jsonTest->>'vehicle' ~ 'color"\s*:\s*"?.*?Blue.*"?';
```

e

```
select * from example
where example.jsonTest->>'vehicle' ~ 'vehicle_type"\s*:\s*"?.*?SUV.*"?';
```

Para  ficar claro deixei um exemplo funcional em https://rextester.com/BQZP48785